# Likert scale questionnaires with ANOVA and Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: anova, references, multiple-comparisons, likert, kruskal-wallis-test

Could someone recommend me sources where I could find *illustrated examples*, solved by hand and/or using software, on how a Likert scale questionnaire (with more than 1 question, say 10, 20, etc. questions; where each question has items to rate, say 3,4, etc; where (0) means disagree and (1) agree or (1) disagree and (5) agree (I think this is a matter of taste?)) "interacts" with ANOVA and Kruskal-Wallis test.

I've seen many examples and plenty of exercises on books but they are always like

- Provides context and some numerical data sets.
- Use of ANOVA (one or two way or repeated) or Kruskal-Wallis.
- and Results.

So far I've never encountered one that in the context considers a Likert-scale questionnaire, data, ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis and results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on a critical edit to your question: Yeah, *sums* of Likert items do not have a Likert distribution. Thanks to the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) they have an approximately normal distribution. Approximately normal data are pretty soundly in ANOVA's bailiwick, (the more items contributing to your outcome variable, the more comfortable with ANOVA you should be), though you will still need to make appropriate corrections for unequal variances between groups.

If the number of Likert-scale items contributing to your variable is small, you might want to use the Kruskal-Wallis test instead. There will be a small hit to statistical power (as compared with ANOVA) using Kruskal-Wallis with approximately normal data, but you should be able to use either.

---

The Kruskal-Wallis test assumes the outcome data measured across $C$ groups are measured *continuously*. I.e., from their original paper "If the samples come from identical ***continuous*** populations, and the $n_{i}$ are not too small, $H$ is distributed as $\chi^{2}(C-1)$…" ($H$ is the Kruskal-Wallis test statistic, and the $n_{i}$s are the sample sizes in each group.)

The same is true of the Mann-Whitney(-Wilcoxon) rank sum test between two samples—which the Kruskal-Wallis test is effectively a $C$ sample extension of—where Mann & Whitney's first sentence is "Let $x$ and $y$ be two random variables with ***continuous*** cumulative distribution functions $f$ and $g$."

Unfortunately, this means that the inferential properties based on the distribution of the $H$ test statistic may be invalid if applied to, for example, ordinal data of only a few values. While Kruskal & Wallis do give corrections for ties, which may arise in *any* continuous variable where $n>10^p$ where $p$ is the precision in number of significant digits, I suspect the test is unreliable for cases where *all* values are tied many times, as would be the case for [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) data with 5-ish or 7-ish values.

At the very least you may expect to find few illustrated examples published which violate an assumption of the test.

**References**
Kruskal, W. H., & Wallis, W. A. (1952). [Use of ranks in one-criterion variance analysis](https://people.ucalgary.ca/~jefox/Kruskal%20and%20Wallis%201952.pdf). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 47(260), 583–621.

Mann, H. B., & Whitney, D. R. (1947). [On A Test Of Whether One Of Two Random Variables Is Stochastically Larger Than The Other](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730491). *Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, 18, 50–60.

Comment: Thanks Alexis for your answer. I'm not sure that I understand your answer, are you saying that one should not use the Kruskal-Wallis test when one have ordinal data from a Likert scale?

Comment: @America That is what I am saying, yes. Sorry if that wasn't clear. :) (Also: welcome to CV!)

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Thank you:) although I've been a member since some time ago, not very active tho.

Comment: What about ANOVA?

Comment: The closest that I have come as an 'illustrated example' are papers, where they use one-way ANOVA, but as you can imagine, they only present the results. I've tried to find examples, like the ones that are in books, but as I said in my post, I've found none, which is kinda strange or I don't know what I could be missing here.

Comment: @America ANOVA also has assumptions about continuous variables—in fact more stringent, since ANOVA assumes continuous *normally distributed* variables. I think for Likert outcomes/dependent variable, I might go to something like [ordered logit regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit), with group as a predicting factor variable.

Comment: Ahh. So is a _no_ for ANOVA too. But then I don't understand why do people use ANOVA when using Likert scale questionnaires?

Comment: I've read the Wikipedia link about ordered logic regression. "...the purpose of the analysis is to see how well that response can be predicted by the responses to other questions, some of which may be quantitative,..." I don't understand how is this related to ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis purposes. Aren't they designed for different purposes, the ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis _and_ ordered logit regression?

Comment: @America People make all sorts of mistakes. Some mistakes even become *standard practice*. From the first sentence from Wikipedia: "the ordered logit model (also ordered logistic regression or proportional odds model) is an ordinal regression model—that is, a regression model for ordinal dependent variables." This is ***precisely*** what Likert outcomes are: *ordinal data*. Presumably you want to look for evidence that, say, some group variable (but really, whatever kind of varible) predicts the value of your Likert variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108102/discussion-between-america-and-alexis).

Comment: while KW test was created for continuous distributions without possible ties, adjustments for discrete variables including possible ties have been proposed. also, likert good practice includes averaging many similar 5-scale answers the same survey, to get a more continuous and also gaussian-ish variable. this justifies ANOVA: even if gaussianity is not really respected (when it is, after all?), the collected p-values are still useful, if rough, and biased, indicators of the significance of the result.

Comment: "People make all sorts of mistakes. Some mistakes even become standard practice". all models are wrong, but some are useful. standard practice makes mistakes comparable and thus useful.

Comment: @carlo Could you explain more this part "likert good practice includes averaging many similar 5-scale answers the same survey, to get a more continuous and also gaussian-ish variable."?

Comment: "the collected p-values are still useful" Hahaha! *Nope!*

Comment: @America when planning a quantitative analysis, it is a good thing to put into surveys many questions that basically ask the same thing. This of course has to be made before data collection. Questions opposites to each other are a particular recommendation. This has many advantages: 1) you can check that answers are coherent, and that the participant was paying attention to the questionnaire; 2) the result is more robust to ambiguity or bad formulation of any singular question; 3) you can make questions that about behaviors that are complex to put in one simple sentence...

Comment: 4) when averaging between all items in the same batch of questions (for the same participant), you get a more continuous variable, and this helps for testing, both parametric and not. for instance, if someone puts 5, 5 and 4 to three items of some questionnaire, about the same issue, it results to be more convinced than someone else that puts three 5s as answers. 5) one can argue that the resulting average, coming from variables that are independent at least for some of their parts, is gaussian, and then t-test is appropriate. this is disputable, but t-tests are disputable almost always.

Comment: @carlo Ah! I see I see... I misunderstood your initial comment about means. Yes: *sums* of Likert items are going to be approximately normal, so game on. (My assumption was that America was considering a *single* Likert scale outcome.)

Comment: I don't know about America, but I hope that when someone is doing t-tests on likert surveys, they have used multiple items averages.

Comment: @carlo I see. That's what I also had thought. I asked something similar  [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465852/why-the-variable-type-is-discrete-ordinal-and-not-interval). Assuming there're 10 or 20 questions, there're will be an average at some point, for example in BruceET's answer we see `[1] 46 62 60 16 16  # Likert scores 1,2,3,4,5, resp
[1] 62 51 85 35 17` . And yes, this scores came from  a Likert scale questionnaire. But we still can use ANOVA or KW (assuming we have more than 2 groups to compare). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alexis oh I see. What I had in mind, was a typical Likert scale questionnaire, which usually has more than 1 question, say 10-20-etc. Sorry for the confusion, I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: about that answer by BruceET, you got it wrong: those are the frequencies of results, for two groups of 200 and 250 participants each, of a single survey question with 5 choices

Comment: @carlo Sorry, that's exactly what I was thinking some minutes ago. So here again, I'm imagining something like this `[20.9 ... 30.2] %group 1` `[40.7 ... 10.8] %group 2` `and so on` and basically done. ANOVA (assuming all the other assumptions hold) would do the rest. Having in mind that those numbers (29.9 ... 30.2) are the average score from a Likert scale from each individual, respectively. In other words, in case I didn't explain myself clearly, it would be something like  this [One-way ANOVA and Post Hoc Test Using SPSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehOWuOcyejI). Am I correct?

Comment: @America Yeah, *sums* of Likert items do not have a Likert distribution. Thanks to the Central Limit Theorem they have an approximately normal distribution.

Comment: @Alexis ahh:) I see then, got it now. Thank you.

Comment: Also, thank you @carlo, if you hadn't commented, then I would have gone with the idea that neither ANOVA nor KW is correct for a Likert scale questionnaire.